# Amazon Lex compared to Botpress

Tags: bots, google-assist-api, amazon-lex

Maybe I'm just taken up by pretty web sites like Botpress.io, but I have a question about bot building platforms.  I've started using Amazon Lex for some bot building and I've since come across Botpress.  Are these essentially competing products?  At face value the answer seems to be yes, but I struggle to understand how Botpress has natural language processing that can be competitive with the big guys like Amazon and Google.

One of the coolest things that Lex does for me is auto translates similar strings of text into utterances for processing.  I'm sure Botpress can do this too in a simplistic way, but would the natural language processing of Lex or Google Assistant be much more powerful?

In this situation why would anybody ever use something like Botpress knowing that the natural language capabilities are much better on other services?

Hope somebody can help me.

Thanks,
L

Answer (score 1):

They are different services that aim to solve different problems. Lex aims to make NLP simpler for developers by giving them access to their powerful NLP service, and Botpress aims to make the building process easier by providing open source modules. They can work together, in theory, and choosing one does not lock you out of the other, necessarily.

---

Amazon Lex specializes in NLP powered by deep learning from Amazon. Lex also provides an automatically scaling infrastructure (Lambda functions), and conversation state management, all baked into the service. Lex has technical depth in NLP and infrastructure.

From the Amazon Lex site:

> Speech recognition and natural language understanding are some of the most challenging problems to solve in computer science, requiring sophisticated deep learning algorithms to be trained on massive amounts of data and infrastructure. Amazon Lex democratizes these deep learning technologies by putting the power of Amazon Alexa within reach of all developers.

Botpress is an open source project that aims to modularize the bot building experience. They do no specialize, or offer, NLP. They make it easy for you to hook someone else's NLP into their service. I do not believe a Lex middleware exists for Botpress, but one could easily be written using Lex's sdk from amazon.

From an npm Botpress module:

> Our philosophy at Botpress is to have a small & powerful core and leverage the best tools available by integrating them as Modules.

From the Botpress website:

> Different tools work well for different jobs. We love the simplicity of tools like Chatfuel, but simplicity should not limit your technical ambitions. Tools like the Microsoft Bot Platform are great, but creating and managing bots should not be reserved only for skilled developers.

Comment: Understood.  However I do have the ability to also deploy my bot automatically on Amazon Lex without needing something like Botpress too right?

Comment: You can connect to messaging channels like slack, fb messenger, alexa from lex. Lex uses lambda functions, which arent deployed so much as created or selected. Lex lets you specify lambda functions or api endpoints for validation and fulfillment logic.